# Firefox show download URLs

Tags: firefox, download, url, about-config

With Firefox, I can select <kbd>History</kbd> <kbd>Show All History</kbd> and
it has a "Location" column with the URLs.

If I select <kbd>Tools</kbd> <kbd>Downloads</kbd>, it shows the size of each
download, but it does not show URLs. It does have a option to
<kbd>Copy Download Link</kbd>, but I would prefer to see the URLs at a glance
if possible

Does Firefox have a setting for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a raw style procedure. Firefox stores the download list in a [SQLite database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite). Let assume that file as a mixture of a spreadsheet table and a dictionary. The name of that file is [places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite) (or sometimes `Places.sqlite`). So, how to find that file? This depends on the Operating System. Here are the probable path of that file. The `random_characters.default` folder can be browsed through a file manager/file explorer.

- Windows: `%Roaming%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\random_characters.default\places.sqlite`
- Linux: `~/.mozilla/firefox/random_characters.default/places.sqlite`

To open that SQLite file, here I choose the [sqlite tool](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) which works with commands. But users may use [SQlite Database browser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) which is a GUI program. Copy the `places.sqlite` file in same folder of `sqlite3.exe` program. Open a terminal in that folder and run this command (requires some SQL programming knowledge):

```sql
sqlite3
.open places.sqlite
SELECT url FROM moz_places WHERE url LIKE '%FileName%';
```

The command opens that SQLite file. Then it searches for the **moz_places** table, selects only the **url** column, and shows the url which contains `FileName`. The percentage signs are wildcards. Change `FileName` with the file URL you want to know. The `FileName` sometimes matches with the **tittle** column.

Here is a screenshot in SQLite Database browser, see the **moz_placs** table and **url** column:

[image: Places_SQLite_DB_Browser]

- Further deatils:

  - [Wikipedia: SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)
  - [KB Mozillazine: Places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite)
  - [SQLite tutorial: install](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download-install-sqlite/)
  - [SQLite tutorial: select statement](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select/)

Answer (score 3):

The free Nirsoft
[FirefoxDownloadsView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/firefox_downloads_view.html)
can replace the Firefox Downloads display :

[image]

Comment: what i mean to say is that its not FOSS

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see download URLs anymore in Firefox, and I'm not aware of any setting to change that. The displayed information was simplified somewhere between Firefox 50 and the current version.

You can however download an extension, that will give you access to an alternative download manager.
For example [Download Manager (S3)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3download-statusbar/), it's licensed under MPL 2.0 and supports latest versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

No, Firefox doesn't have a setting for this. You can "Copy Download Link" (like you already noticed) or "Go To Download Page", but you cannot see the URLs at a glance. You can see the domain (like example.com) next the size and the date for the downloads, but not the full link.

You can use 3rd party software, as @harrymc suggested, to do this.